# Python ImportError: cannot import name '_device' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I try opening jupyter notebook from Anaconda Prompt, I am getting this error:

> **ImportError: cannot import name '_device' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import).**

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?